# .SELECT statement using lambda and Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, select, lambda

I am struggling here in using *`.SELECT`* statement.

Here a snippet of my code;

```
var payoutsPerLocation = locations.Select(l => l.Payouts);

foreach (var payouts in payoutsPerLocation)
{
    Console.WriteLine(payouts.Sum(pos=>pos.Amount));
}
```

Where in location is a list, and one location has one or more payout. I want to get all the payouts.

The above code's result is below

```
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

It should be the sum of the amount of payouts per location. It seems like I don't get any records of payout. But when I tried using the code below (for testing if I am getting payout);

```
var payoutsPerLocation = locations.FirstOrDefault().Payouts;

foreach (var payout in payoutsPerLocation)
{
    Console.WriteLine(payout.Amout);
}
```

There is a payout for that location. What do you guys think I am doing wrong here?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The code looks fine, so something else is the problem. Are you sure that `Amount` is non-0? Does it work if you write the code without LINQ?

Comment: Hi @Gabe , I'm sure that the `Amount` is not zero. I am getting the correct record when I am using the `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: Please include the class definition for `Location`. I suspect that `Location.Payouts` is not virtual.

Comment: Hi @Aron.Rows for `Location.Payouts` is added before the code above is performed using `locations.Payouts.Add(payout)`. So basically, it is not yet saved in database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why it's giving you zeros, but you shouldn't evaluate Linq expressions inside a foreach loop anyway. It causes too many round-trips to the database. Try this:

```
var sumPerLocation = locations.Select(l => l.Payouts.Sum(p => p.Amount));
foreach (var sum in sumPerLocation)
{
    Console.WriteLine(sum);
}
```

Comment: This is not probably what I am looking for. Thanks, though!

Comment: @janmallari: That's fine, but it's difficult for me or others to offer any further suggestions if you don't explain why this doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Marcelo Cantos! It's my first time posting here. Let me rephrase my comment. Tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. It still get zeroes. When I tried getting the query made, it says that it selects location. Sorry, i'm a newbie in programming. T.T

Comment: @janmallari: I suggest you profile the database to see what SQL is being generated, and then rerun the query in SSMS to see what it returns. You'll also find that my code and yours behave quite differently in profiler, which is why my refactoring advice still holds.

Comment: I already figured out this one. Instead of creating `payouts` variable and putting `locations.Select(l=>l.Payouts)`, I used `var location in locations` in my `foreach` statement and get the `payouts` per location. Marked your answer as well for your kind and honest comment/ tip for me. :)

Comment: @janmallari: Thanks, but I still strongly suggest you do the profiling to see what kind and (more importantly) how many queries are being run when you use your original code, my answer, and your final code. Evaluating IQueryable expressions inside a `foreach` loop is almost always a bad idea.

Comment: thanks for the tip! Will surely do that on my next few development.